# How do I disable showing the "Activities overview" forever?

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview

With two monitors connected, the "Activities overview" is very annoying me when every time I click the applications button on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It annoyed me too, but specifically because its very dark background color, that I couldn't seem to be able to adjust. But I have dug up a way to adjust its background color, and now it does not disturb me any more. Here is how I did it: https://askubuntu.com/q/1305080/1157519

Answer (score 5):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called **[Hide Activities Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/744/hide-activities-button/)**. This extension hides the *Activities* button from the top bar.

Note that you'll still be able access the *Activities* overview by pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (usually the key with Windows logo).

Similar extension: [*Hide Activities Button*](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1128/hide-activities-button/) (same name, different extension)

Comment: Thanks but is there any way to disabled the Activities Overview even when I press the Super key or click on the "Applications" button in left bottom corner?

Comment: @Devymex Run the following command in Terminal `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-show-apps-button false` to get rid of the "Show Applications" icon.

Comment: In addition to this, you also may disable the <Super> key, and disable (or change) the <Super+a>, <Super+s> and <Alt+F1) hotkeys. Then you will have a hard time showing the activities or applications overview.

Comment: I want neither to hide the "Show Applications" button nor disable the Super key, but just disable the "Activities Overview" when I press super key or click on the "Show Applications". Is it possible?

Comment: @Devymex Could you clarify? When you click "Show Applications", you should see the app screen with frequent and all apps, not the "Activities Overview". Are you experiencing something else?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! I just realized the "Activities Overview" will shown up only if two monitors is connected! The Master monitor shows the "Applications" and the slave monitor shows the annoying "Activities Overview". The "Activities Overview" showing up with a very slow animation and I need press Esc twice to close it. I do not want my slave monitor is covered by any panel when the "Applications" shown up.

Comment: @Devymex were you able to change the behavior?

Comment: @saurjk I use an extension named "ClassicMenu Indicator" which can be found in the "Ubuntu Software" to help to get rid of the "activies view".  And I manually disable and hid the original start menu forever. Btw, the ClassicalMenu Indicator is really a great extension, very helpful.

Comment: some how to details would be nice.

Comment: @Liberated It's there. Click link with the text 'GNOME Shell extension', it would take you [this canonical Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481).

Answer (score 3):

The activities overview is core to Gnome Shell, so can as such not be disabled. You can, however, configure Gnome Shell to make access to the overview much less immediate.

**1) Replace or hide the Activities button**

*Replace the Activities button by a traditional menu*: Install "Applications Menu" or "Arc Menu" to see your Activities button replaced by a button that opens a classical menu.

*Hide the Activities button*: Install the extension "Hide Activities" to hide the button. In that case, you will want to install an alternative launcher program, for example ULauncher, Albert or Rofi.

**2) Disable the Super key and other shortcut keys**

Issue following commands to disable 1) the Super key 2) the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, 3) the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> key and the 4) <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut keys, which open either the Activities or the Applications overview.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-overview "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-application-view "['']"
```

**3) Disable hot corner**

Not needed on stock Ubuntu, because it is already disabled by default. If you need to disable it, you can do so using Gnome Tweaks or with the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-hot-corners false
```

This will largely place the overview out of your view.

**Installing the extensions:**

All mentioned extensions are available in the official Ubuntu software sources. You can install them from Snap Center or with the terminal command `sudo apt install <packagename>`. After installing them, you need to enable them on a per user basis, using Gnome Tweaks, or, on more recent Ubuntu versions, the "Extensions" tool. The latter is available through the package `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`, the former in `gnome-tweaks`.

"Applications Menu" can be installed through the package `gnome-shell-extensions`. This package also contains all other officially supported Gnome Shell extensions.

"Arc Menu" can be installed through the package `gnome-shell-extension-arc-menu`.

"Hide Activities" is available through the package `gnome-shell-extension-hide-activities`

**Undo the settings**

To undo the settings, you can reset to default by issuing similar commands, where you replace `set` by `reset` and omit the last argument.